# Vyos: How to enable prior disabled Nat rules

Tags: linux, router, vyos

Vyos ver. 1.1.8

When in configuration mode, you can easily disable a NAT rule by using the "disabled" argument. E.g.:

```
set destination nat rule 10 disabled
```

But how to enable it again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by "deleting" the "disabled" ...

```
delete destination nat rule 10 disabled
commit
save
```

This will remove only the "disabled" component not the whole rule.